# How to know how many frames will be needed to transmit a file

Tags: cisco, ethernet, wireshark

How many frames will be neeed to transmit a file of 80,480 KB file? Is there a mathematical calculation for this?

Comment: That depends on the frame payload size, and the layer-3 and layer-4 overheads. You have not provided nearly enough information to answer the question.

Comment: This is the only information I have. So what I need to research in order to answer this question?

Comment: You need to know the protocols at layers 2 through 4, including which options they may have which may affect the header length. You will also need to know the path MTU, and what, if any, application protocol overhead there may be.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like a homework question.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no straight answer just as there's no magical formula to get this. Frames are layer 2 and some of them they carry layer 3 packets, which contain layer 3 protocol info as well as data payload, but not necessarily in the same packet.

A partial answer is "at least the same amount of packets needed to transmit the file", and so the amount of packets varies depending on MTU which will fragment the packet size; it varies if there's noise in the link which can lead to packet loss and therefore packet retransmission; it also depends on the application used to transmit the file: ftp, scp, sftp, etc or even tftp, while the first are tcp (allowing packet retransmission), tftp for example uses udp and doesn't really care if the packet was delivered.

So, there's a number of things to take into consideration before giving a definite answer. I would setup a wireshark sniffer and perform a transfer test just for fun and check all the capture information to see how much of it is data vs how much is protocol info.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  You certainly can calculate how many *at least* if you know your maximum transmission unit, MTU.  You are speaking of frames which is layer2.  So, simply do the math.  Assuming approximately 1500 bytes for Ethernet.

80,480 KB (Filesize) / 1.5 KB (MTU) = 53653.33 frames.

Comment: Troll downvote, or is my answer wrong?